# All of the my code is gone after I inserted an image literal on my Swift playground

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I tried to insert an image on my playground. After I clicked the button called "insert image literal" and all of my code is gone.

How do I find it back?

I am new to Swift and just started out from my previous job a while ago and I have searched on Google. I knew it might be a stupid question but these are my practice work for a long time and I really need to have it back.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try with command+Z to redo your action

Comment: @Kingalione You mean command+Z to *undo*. Redo is not what the OP needs.

Comment: oh yeah undo sorry for my bad english

Comment: If you can't undo for some reason hopefully you either have version control on the playground so you can revert or TimeMachine that has an old copy you can revert to.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. Unfortunately it was all gone and I found the possible reason that it might because its just a playground and I should never save the codes in the playground instead of the project.. its just a tool i use for practicing writing codes... I have re-wrote all my codes again and its kinda irritating but in the end it was worthing... Thank you all and hopefully I can get on the road as soon as possible so i can try to answer some of others questions here..